# How to retrieve text from an element using Selenium WebDriver and Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to retrieve text of an element with == $0. I tried to use JS injection 
`((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].value", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.settings span")))`
    but this approach returns NULL for me 
 [image]

Comment: Can you check in developer console how many entries are present with locator `div.settings span` ?

Comment: Can you try this , let me know if this works ? `WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.settings span"));
String myText = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;", myElement);
System.out.println(myText);`

Comment: @DenisS. You don't retrieve the CSS path as such, rather you use CssSelector to identify elements. Are you are  trying to retrieve any text?

Comment: @cruisepandey Seems the `<placeholder>` within the comments clearly says **Avoid answering questions in comments**. Comments are not useful as answers. Please take care.

Comment: @DebanjanB : OP is not clear, so it's always better to give alternate solution in case if it works. Need more info.

Comment: Incase the question is not clear the correct approach is to ask for more information ... right? But not to answer within comments ... agree?

Comment: @cruisepandey, ```div.settings span``` locates one entry  [span.label]

Comment: @DebanjanB, sorry, yes, i'm trying to get the text. I expect to get back ```shooting``` and ```pedestrian accident```

Comment: Which text are you trying to extract?

Comment: @cruisepandey,  the following script ```WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.settings span")); String myText = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;", myElement); System.out.println(myText);``` returns only ```OR```. But i need to get ```shooting``` and ```pedestrian accident```

Comment: DebanjanB, ```shooting``` and ```pedestrian accident```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the texts **Shooting** and **Pedestrian Accident** are within elements which are *text nodes*, so to extract the texts you can use the following solutions:

```
WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.settings")); 
//extracting Shooting
System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;", myElement).toString());
//extracting Pedestrian Accident
System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", myElement).toString());
```