# How to extract the population figure of a country from en.wikipedia.org using Selenium through Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to extract the population figure/text of an element.

I tried with parent but its showing error. I am trying to get the **Population** of China from this page table `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China`

Code trial:

```
WebElement dateBox7 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Population')]/parent::tr//td/a[text()]"));
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
```

I have tried `//*[contains(text(),'2016 estimate')]/ancestor::tr/td/text()[1]` this xpath it's showing the population in DOM.But in selenium it's showing error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*[contains(text(),'2016 estimate')]/ancestor::tr/td/text()[1]" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

Why it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this xpath

```
"//*[contains(.,'Population')]/parent::tr//th/a[text()]"
```

Note there are two changes: `td` -> `th`, and `[contains(text(),'Population')]` -> `[contains(.,'Population')]`.

When searching for `[contains(.,'Population')]` the "dot" means searching all text inside of the element (including the descendants) while "text()" will search only for the direct textural content of the element.

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment, try this xpath:

```
"//*[contains(.,'Population')]/parent::tr/following-sibling::tr[1]/td"
```

**EDIT #2:**

For a tutorial on Xpath locators, see [here](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html) and for a free course on the topic see [here](https://testautomationu.applitools.com/web-element-locator-strategies).

Comment: but it's not showing the population of china 1,403,500,365.I tried this //*[contains(text(),'2016 estimate')]/ancestor::tr/td/text()[1]   But showing error i described in post comment section.

Comment: Ah, I see. You are looking at the wrong element. I'll give you the right xpath soon.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the the Population of China i.e. the text **1,403,500,365** from this page table `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and as the desired text is within a *Text Node* you need to use `executeScript()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

```
WebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[text()='Population']//following::tr[1]//td"))); 
System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;", myElement).toString());
```

> You can find a similar discussion in [How to retrieve text from an element using Selenium WebDriver and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699041/how-to-retrieve-text-from-an-element-using-selenium-webdriver-and-java/55711031#55711031)