# How to write a Xpath for Showing text in console which is separated using <br> tag?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

How to write a Xpath for Showing text in console which is separated  using 
 tag?

url: http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlcheckboxes.php

```
<div class="display"> Please select every sport that you play.
    <br> Soccer:
    <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="soccer">
    <br> Football:
    <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="football">
    <br> Baseball:
    <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="baseball">
    <br> Basketball:
    <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="basketball">
    <br>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the xpaths like:

```
//div[@class='display']/input[@value='football']
//div[@class='display']/input[@value='baseball']
//div[@class='display']/input[@value='basketball']
```

But, for each of these xpaths, you get 2 objects as shown below(for example, Football):
[image]

So, for this particular case, if you need to select say `Football` checkbox under the header HTML Checkbox Form, then you several options like:

- By Index: `//div[@class='display'][1]/input[@value='football']`
- By finding a static object between 2 similar objects i.e, If, in this case, I want to select the `Football` checkbox that comes **before** the static header **HTML Pre-Selected Checkboxes**(refer image), we can write something like:

  `//h2[contains(text(),'HTML Pre-Selected Checkboxes')]/preceding-sibling::div/input[@value='football']`

  If we wanted to select the 2nd Football checkbox, we know it comes **after** the header **HTML Pre-Selected Checkboxes**, so could have very well written the xpath:

  `//h2[contains(text(),'HTML Pre-Selected Checkboxes')]/following-sibling::div/input[@value='football']`

Answer (score 0):

The texts *Soccer:*, *Football:*, *Baseball:*, *Basketball:* etc are within [*Text Node*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55699041/how-to-retrieve-text-from-an-element-using-selenium-webdriver-and-java/55711031#55711031). So to extract the texts  you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  // printing Soccer:
  System.out.println((String)((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[2].textContent;", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='display']"))));

  // printing Football:
  System.out.println((String)((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[5].textContent;", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='display']"))));

  // printing Baseball:
  System.out.println((String)((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[8].textContent;", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='display']"))));

  // printing Basketball:
  System.out.println((String)((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[11].textContent;", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='display']"))));
  ```

Answer (score -1):

You can try below **Xpath** and use the **element** to extract text from the same. Please clarify if this is not what you are asking for.

```
//div[@class='display'][1]
```

After finding the element, you can either use **`.text`** or **`.get_attribute("innerText")`** methods to display the required text in the console.

```
driver.get("http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlcheckboxes.php")

data = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='display'][1]")

# Using `.text`
print(data.text)

# Using `.get_attribute("innerText")`
print(data.get_attribute("innerText"))
```

For both the methods the output is:

```
Please select every sport that you play.
Soccer:
Football:
Baseball:
Basketball:
```